# Is it possible to create a new web site page outside of wordpress and FTP upload to wordpress site?

Tags: php, python, wordpress, ftp

I'm getting the sense a singe HTML page is not something Wordpress will work with but I'd like to make the code for a new page in however many files that takes and and have a script in Python upload and make them live on a Wordpress site with FTP.
Is this possible?
I'll be making a lot of new pages so I don't have time to copy and paste into the Wordpress 'new post' feature.

I'm using wordpress for the plugins so maybe I should not use wordpress and my question should be: What are my plugin options for a sight that uses and HTML file for each page. HELP!
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress stores posts and pages in database not files. **You won't be able to use FTP** for uploading content. But you can use python to interact with the WordPress API as @JosepVails stated.

There is a python module for this you can find it at: [python-wordpress-xmlrpc](https://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Example for adding posts:

```
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts import NewPost

wp = Client('http://example.com/xmlrpc.php', 'username', 'password')

post = WordPressPost()
post.title = 'My new title'
post.content = 'This is the body of my new post.'
post.terms_names = {
  'post_tag': ['test', 'firstpost'],
  'category': ['Introductions', 'Tests']
}

wp.call(NewPost(post))
```

Comment: Awesome! So with post.content, could I pass an HTML file into this?  
Any way to quarantine some new posts from a most popular/ trending posts of the day widget while giving the sorting widget ten to arrange on the front page?

Comment: Yes, you can add HTML to your post or page. As for the second question, I don't know which plugin you are referring, but you can make a new question adding more details.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to mess with FTP. Wordpress provided an API you can use to post content to your website and you can definitely use a Python script to generate content and post to the API. See: https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API